# Calendar library customisation advice

Tags: codeigniter

CodeIgniter has a nice calendar library, but my calendar requirements are a little specific. I would need to display only calendar dates for a range of specific days. For example, Mondays, or Mondays and Fridays, or just weekdays.

For example, Mondays for this month would look like;

```
<< Mondays in April >>
  [4] [11] [18] [25]
```

I've read the docs and looked at some tutorials, but haven't learned how to do this myself.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this with the existing calendar library, or would it be better to build something like this from scratch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your own made template and extend Calendar class, but It would be troublesome. I think Codeigniter doesn't have the right tool straight of the box for your situation. I would propose [calendR](http://yohan.giarel.li/CalendR/). I would parse desired month and took f.e. mondays using API, especially CalendR\Period\Day which has constant MONDAY.